# Altering the location of Oracle-Suggested Backup

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, rman, oracle-database-appliance, oracle-enterprise-manager

On one database, the Oracle-Suggested Backup scheduled from Enterprise Manager always ends up in the recovery area, despite RMAN configuration showing that device type disk format points elsewhere.

As far as I can see, the scheduled backup job is simply:

```
run {
allocate channel oem_disk_backup device type disk;
recover copy of database with tag 'ORA_OEM_LEVEL_0';
backup incremental level 1 cumulative  copies=1 for recover of copy with tag 'ORA_OEM_LEVEL_0' database;
}
```

Asking RMAN to `show all` reveals that device type disk is indeed configured to store elsewhere:

```
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT   '/s01/backup/PROD11/PROD11_%U';
```

If I run the script manually,  the backupset is placed at the above location, when the script is run from the job scheduler the backupset goes to the RECO group on ASM,

Why might Oracle still choose to dump the backupset to the `db_recovery_file_dest`?

Ultimately, how can I change the backup destination?

Comment: Whenever the recovery area is enabled it will use by default the fast recovery area... this Oracle documentation might help you as well: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/backup.1111/e10642/rcmconfb.htm Thanks.

Comment: That is all well and good, but I'm not really using the default. I have specifically set the file format/location in the generic channel configuration for the device type. This is working fine on all but one ODA hosted database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot say for sure why RMAN behaves in this way, but as a workaround you can edit the resulting script within the same workflow in EM before the job is created:

```
 ALLOCATE CHANNEL disk1 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/disk1/%d_backups/%U';
```

This will ensure the backups are placed in the destination you specified regardless of RMAN settings in control file saved with `CONFIGURE` command.